# Filling a pandas data frame with values from another data frame (combinations)

Tags: python, pandas

This is a little exercise in combinations and pandas.

I currently have a pandas data frame like:

| node1 | node2| distance|
|Sydney|Canberra|100|
|Melbourne| Sydney| 200|
|Canberra| Melbourne| 150|

I then create a new data frame so column headers and row names are the unique values of the nodes.

```
mat = pd.DataFrame(index = np.unique(df.node1), columns = np.unique(df.node1))
```

Either node1 or node2 would suffice here as order doesn't matter when constructing the data frame.

Which produces what I want but filled with NaN values.

How do I go about filling mat with the values from distance column without writing some ugly loop?

Thanks

Comment: Are columns and index created by `node1` ?

Comment: can you add the combos dataframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
mat = df.pivot(index='node1', columns='node2', values='distance')
print (mat)
node2      Canberra  Melbourne  Sydney
node1                                 
Canberra        NaN      150.0     NaN
Melbourne       NaN        NaN   200.0
Sydney        100.0        NaN     NaN
```

---

```
mat = df.set_index(['node1', 'node2'])['distance'].unstack()
print (mat)
node2      Canberra  Melbourne  Sydney
node1                                 
Canberra        NaN      150.0     NaN
Melbourne       NaN        NaN   200.0
Sydney        100.0        NaN     NaN
```

And then [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
mat = mat.combine_first(mat.T)
print (mat)
           Canberra  Melbourne  Sydney
node1                                 
Canberra        NaN      150.0   100.0
Melbourne     150.0        NaN   200.0
Sydney        100.0      200.0     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael I forgot about pivot. Additional question, is there a way I can also populate the reverse e.g. Sydney -> Canberra = 100 great! but also populate Canberra -> Sydney = 100 ?

Comment: In fact if I make mat2 = df.pivot(index='node2', columns='node1', values='distance') I will get the reverse. Now I need a way to merge these two data frames.

Comment: Yes, or then use `df1.combine_first(df2`